# DatePicker in autogenerated gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetimepicker

I am having autogenerated gridview which took all the data from db. I want to add DateTimePicker to the fields with specific column name.
I tried with DateTimePicker class but it doesn`t work because after creating the field I have to add it to Grid control and it shows me error:
"Cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker' to 'System.Web.UI.Control'" .

Do you have any ideas how i can add DatePicker to the gridview without using html?

My code in c# for checking the name of the column (it is working as it has to the only problem is with creating DateTimePicker in c# code):

`if (DataTable.Columns[i].ToString() == "start_date_time") {  System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker dp = new System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker();  dp.Name = "DateTimePicker"; DBTableGrid.Rows[0].Cells[i + 1].Controls.Add(dp); }`

Gridview code:

`<asp:GridView ID="DBTableGrid" runat="server" CssClass="GridDataStyle" HeaderStyle-CssClass="GridStyleHeader" RowStyle-CssClass="GridStyleRows" PagerStyle-CssClass="GridStylePager" PageSize="10" AllowPaging="true" OnPageIndexChanging="Grid_Projects" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True"> </asp:GridView>`

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you show us your specific code?

Comment: if (DataTable.Columns[i].ToString() == "start_date_time")
                    {
                        System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker dp = new System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker();
                        dp.Name = "DateTimePicker";
                        DBTableGrid.Rows[0].Cells[i + 1].Controls.Add(dp);
                        
                    }

Comment: Please update the question with codes